# Framework 'FaceDetector' Not Found

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project which I haven't built in a while which when I build the project I get the following error: Framework 'FaceDetector' not found (see screenshot).[image]

My podfile includes this line: `#pod 'GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector'`, but I do not see this framework anywhere in my project. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line is `#pod 'GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector'` it means you or someone else commented out the pod. It won't be installed.

Viewing the `podfile` in Xcode will show the item dimmed. e.g  This spec will only install `Purchases`:

[image]

Change the line to `pod 'GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector'`.

then `pod install` again.

Comment: I tried uncommenting the pod and doing pod install but I am still seeing the error Framework 'FaceDetector' not found including Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: doing pod deintegrate and pod install after uncommenting the line seems to have resolved the issue.